# is there any way to access the python list variable inside jinja with the for loop(in jinja) in Djnago?

Tags: python, html, django

```
<tr>
   {%for i in desc %}
   <td>{{desc[i]}}</td>
   {%endfor%}
</tr>
```

[I get this result when i run above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK6a5.png)

Comment: How did you render the template?

Answer (score 1):

sorry it was a silly mistake there, now i solved this:

```
<tr>
   {%for i in desc %}
   <td>{{i}}</td>
   {%endfor%}
</tr
```